# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<QuickTest.Stock>'

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        List<Stock> ticker = new List<Stock>();
        ticker.Add(new Stock("msft"));
        ticker.Add(new Stock("acw"));
        ticker.Add(new Stock("gm"));

        ticker = ticker.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();

        foreach (Stock s in ticker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        ticker = ticker.RemoveAll(s => s.TickerSymbol == "gm");

        foreach (Stock s in ticker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        }
    }
```

Stock is an object that has string properties TickerSymbol and Name. It also has double properties Price, ChangeDollars, and ChangePercent.

The second LINQ statement I wrote is throwing an error with the message, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'". I am confused as to where the type 'int' is coming from and how to fix this error, as I dont use any int values anywhere in the program.

I am very new to LINQ as well, this is my first time using it. This error could very well be a result of some intricacy of LINQ that I am not aware of.

Anyone know why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `RemoveAll` will not return a new list, it will modify the existing list and returns the number of records removed.

Comment: Your second LINQ statement isn't a LINQ statement at all. All it does is call `RemoveAll` on the list

Comment: @dcastro Is it not an inline LINQ statement?

Comment: @mstagg you're probably talking about the `x => y` expression. That's called a lambda expression, it's a syntax to define delegates, not linq. LINQ is, to put it simply, a set of extension methods defined for all collections, such as Select, Where, OrderBy. These methods make heavy use of lambda expressions and delegates, why is probably what confused you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is reasonable the error you get, because `RemoveAll` returns the number of removed stocks. This is an integer. Then you try to assign this to the variable called `ticker`, which holds a list of objects of type `Stock`.

That you probably want is to remove all the Stocks that their `TickerSymbol` is `gm` and then write the Stocks that they have been left in ticker to the console. In order to do so, you could just try this:

```
// This will remove all the stocks you want.
ticker.RemoveAll(s => s.TickerSymbol == "gm");

foreach (Stock s in ticker)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
}
```

Furthermore, for the record,  as it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

The method `List<T>.RemoveAll()`

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate.

It's signature is the following:

```
public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)
```

The `Predicate<T>` is a delegate to a method that returns true if the object passed to it matches the conditions defined in the delegate. The elements of the current List are individually passed to the Predicate delegate, *and the elements that match the conditions are removed from the List*.

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is List's Count property.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I don't know how I overlooked that. any hint on how to return a new instance of the list with the specified object removed?

Comment: @mstagg You welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped. You could just return the `ticker`, after  having called the `RemoveAll`. The latter will have removed all the elements that you didn't want.